# Selenium doesn't load in Jupyter, but works in Python3 in console and Sublime Text

Tags: python, selenium, pip, jupyter

I'm trying to load selenium in a Jupyter Notebook running Python 3. When I try to import Selenium I get a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'" error. This doesn't happen when I run the same command from Python 3 in the Terminal or using Sublime Text.

I've tried a number of fixes, but can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Jupyter was running a different version of Python3 than my terminal. I found the discrepancy using `which python3` in the terminal and

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

I then specified pip3 from the path given by the latter command and voila, it worked!